# Descargar Archivos por WebView en React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

tengo una aplicación, en ella tengo un WebView, en la página que está en el webview hay una opción de descargar un pdf dinámico, lo cual el webview no reacciona a la opción de guardar o descargar archivo.

> `Dinámico` quiere decir que el PDF se construye en el **servidor**.

Si hay algún método quisiera saberlo, se les agradece su tiempo.

Saludos.